# PyCharm crashes when TensorFlow runs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm

I have installed TensorFlow as any other package and import statement as such looks fine i.e. without any error (red line) marking it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

However, when I try to run the file(with no other statement at all), I get the following message on console:

```
Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)
```

How can I remediate this?

Comment: Does this work when you run the file from command line?

Comment: From the CL, it is ever more bewildering. My file is named "cats_and_dogs.py" and the only line that is inside the file is "import tensorflow as tf". When I run the file from CL, I see - "Illegal instruction: 4"

Comment: It looks like you have installed the wrong architecture, for example `x86_64` version on an `x86` computer. Please verify that your OS, python and package architectures are the same.

Comment: I am using Mac with 3.2 GHz Intel Core i3, which apparently is 64 bit.

Comment: Try by reinstalling the Pycharm and tensorflow in it. Please follow the instructions given in [this](https://shekhargulati.com/2019/03/31/machine-learning-using-tensorflow-and-pycharm-series-part-1-setting-up-environment-and-writing-our-first-tensorflow-program/#:~:text=On%20Mac%2C%20go%20to%20PyCharm,Install%20Package%20to%20install%20TensorFlow.) link to install tensorflow in Pycharm and run your program again. Let us know if issue still persists.